# Joomla Framework : Getting Started Guide

Tags: joomla-framework-1.x

I've been working for joomla CMS for years, and now the project got more complex and its time for me to build custom solution beyond the CMS.

Now, I tried to find books about the Joomla Framework and online courses, but there's none.

I found a tutorial series called [Joomla Framework Solutions](http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/framework-solutions.html) by Andrew Eddie
but the step one (getting started) has problem as the output keep 'telling me':

```
"Configuration file could not be parsed"
```

So, is there a dummy guide for Joomla Framework?

Answer (score 4):

## Tutorials

[Creating a Stand-alone Application](http://docs.joomla.org/Framework%3aCreating_a_Stand-alone_Application), from Joomla! Documentation

[How to develop a web app with Joomla framework](http://www.escope.cz/en/blog/116-how-to-develop-a-web-app-with-joomla-framework), by escope.cz

## Project examples

- David Hurley has created a sample app running on the Framework, called [Joomla! Framework Sample Application.](https://github.com/dbhurley/framework-app)

Answer (score 2):

I've pushed a working CRUD example on the intermediate branch of Michael's fork
https://github.com/mbabker/framework-app/tree/intermediate

You can clone it, and run

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

from the clone's location to install the framework. The above command should take care of creating the configuration file for you. Worst case you can manually create a Config.json file in the /App/Config folder by copying the Config.dist.json